# Nuxt3 and PrimeVue DataTable - Exporting to XLSX Format with Image In Cells

Tags: vuejs3, export, xlsx, nuxt3, primevue

I'm using PrimeVue's DataTable component in a Nuxt 3 project, and I'm trying to export the table data to an XLSX file. The primary reason for choosing this file format is to be able to include images in the cells.

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
function exportCSVHandler() {

  const data = props.data;

  const fields = selectedColumns.value.map((col) => col.field);


  const filteredData = data.map((item) => {
    const filteredItem = {};
    fields.forEach((field) => {
      filteredItem[field] = item[field];
    });
    return filteredItem;
  });


  
  if (dataTableRef.value) {
    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(filteredData);


    const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet 1');

    
    const fileName = 'exported_data.xlsx';
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, fileName);
   
  }
}
```

Here is the data table

```
<Button label="download" @click="exportCSVHandler" />
<DataTable
    ref="dataTableRef"
    v-model:filters="filters"
    :value="filteredData"
    show-gridlines
    paginator
    responsive-layout="scroll"
    :rows="5"
    :row-hover="true"
    data-key="id"
    filter-display="menu"
    overlay-visible
    striped-rows
    csv-separator
    :global-filter-fields="['filled_on', 'text_filled']"
    paginator-template="FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink CurrentPageReport RowsPerPageDropdown"
    current-page-report-template="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries"
    @update:filters="onFilterChange">
  <template #header>
   
    <DataTableFilters
      :filters="filters"
      :hasFilterActions="props.hasFilterActions"
      :typefilter="typefilter"
      @filterData="filterData"
      @clearFilter="clearFilter"
    />

    <div class="text-left mt-7 w-3/4 sm:w-full text-sm">
      <MultiSelect
        v-model="selectedColumns"
        :options="columns"
        optionLabel="header"
        display="chip"
        placeholder="Select Columns"
      />
    </div>

  </template>
  <template #empty>
    Select a template to display data.
  </template>
  <template #loading>
    Loading data. Please wait.
  </template>
  <Column
    v-for="(column, index) of selectedColumns"
    :field="column.field"
    :header="column.header"
    :key="column.field + '_' + index"
    :data-type="column.data_type"
    :style="column.style"
    :filter-field="column.filterField"
    :show-filter-match-modes="column.showFilterMatchModes"
    :filter-menu-style="{ width: '14rem' }"
  >
  <template #body="{ data }">
    <div v-if="column.header === 'Image'">
     
      <div class=" flex justify-content-center">
          <Button icon="pi pi-eye" outlined text  @click="toggleDialog(index, data[column.field])"/>       
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="column.header === 'Filled On'">
      <i class="pi pi-calendar text-primaryBlue font-bold mr-4 text-xl"></i>
      {{ formatDate(data[column.field]) }}
    </div>
    <div v-else class="flex ">
      
      {{ data[column.field] }}
    </div>
  </template>
    
  <template v-if="column.data_type === 'date'" #filter="{ filterModel }">
    <Calendar
      v-model="filterModel.value"
      date-format="mm/dd/yy"
      placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
      mask="99/99/9999"
    />
  </template>
    
  <template v-else-if="column.header !== 'Image'" #filter="{ filterModel }">
    <InputText
      v-model="filterModel.value"
      type="text"
      class="p-column-filter"
      :placeholder="getPlaceholder(column.header)"
    />
  </template>
</Column>
</DataTable>
```

Here is the data format

```
const data = [
{
    id: 6,
    filled_on: new Date('2024-04-22'),
    image: 'https://assets-global.website-files.com/5ebb0930dd82631397ddca92/61b8ef1f82c1b3167fe39e0a_product-template-forms-finance.png',
    text_filled: 'Sed Do Eiusmod',
    type: 'Paper',
    templateName: 'Temp1',
  },
]
```

I tried different libraries and converting image links to base64(ERROR: text length must not exceed 32767 characters), I haven't been successful.